# Java Firestore query snapshot returning string rather than boolean

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to map my query results from `firestore` back to a class in my java application.

I have saved this as a `Boolean` on the web console, see the image:

[image]

And then on the app I use the following function to map this to my class:

```
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        List<uk.wefix.FirestoreModels.Job> mJobsList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                uk.wefix.FirestoreModels.Job job = document.toObject(uk.wefix.FirestoreModels.Job.class);
                mJobsList.add(job);
            }
            mjobsAdaptor.clear();
            mjobsAdaptor.addAll(mJobsList);
        } else {
            Log.d("JobsFragment", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

And the class it maps to:

```
public class Job {

    public String first_name;
    public String second_name;
    public String phone_number;
    public Boolean complete;

    public Job() {}

    public Job(String first_name, String second_name, String phone_number, Boolean complete) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.second_name = second_name;
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
        this.complete = complete;
    }

    /**
     * @return String
     */
    public String getFirst_name(){
        return first_name;
    }

    /**
     * @return String
     */
    public String getSecond_name(){
        return second_name;
    }

    /**
     * @return String
     */
    public String getPhone_number(){
        return phone_number;
    }

    /**
     * @return Boolean
     */
    public Boolean getComplete(){
        return complete;
    }
}
```

It seems like Firestore is returning a `String` instead of a `Boolean` which means I get the following error out:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert value of type java.lang.String to boolean (found in field 'complete')
```

Obviously I could just do something like this in the `Job` class, but that seems a bit hacky and I am not sure if this is just a bug or if I am doing something wrong.

Potential 'hacky' solution

```
/**
 * @return Boolean
 */
public Boolean getComplete(){
    if(complete.equals("true")){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Query:

```
CollectionReference jobs = db.collection("jobs");
Query query = jobs.whereEqualTo("technician_id", 10).whereEqualTo("date", "2018-12-12");
```

Comment: At which line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: `uk.wefix.FirestoreModels.Job job = document.toObject(uk.wefix.FirestoreModels.Job.class);`

Comment: How is your `query` defined? And are you sure that the `complete` property does not hold a String value in one or more documents?

Comment: I think it might be a firestore bug, I created that field in the console, but a field I populated using php works fine

Comment: I doubt it. Please show me how is your query defined.

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: Looks good to me. Hoe many documents do you have beneth `jobs` collection?